# How to Display content of json/csv file on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, flask-restful

Using flask, I have listed a few JSON/CSV file in HTML page.
 Now when I click on the hyperlink, the file is getting downloaded. But what I want is that the content of the file to be displayed on the site itself (and possibly in a different page with uri same as filename).

I am blocked with this issue. Can anyone please answer what is the issue here?

part of the flask code

```
@app.route('/<path:req_path>')
def dir_listing(req_path):
    abs_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, req_path)
    # Check if path is a file and serve
    if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
        return send_file(abs_path)    
    # Show directory contents
    files = os.listdir(abs_path)
    return render_template('file_list.html', files=files)
```

file_list.html

```html
<ul>
    {% for file in files %}
    <li><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

View of the '/' page -

[image: html page view]

Comment: You need to respond with the Content-Type header of text/html when serving the json files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: @Jerinaw this works - 
        return send_file(abs_path, mimetype="application/json"). But how can make it jsonify in the html page?

Comment: BTW, your comments helped me.

Comment: Cool, up vote the comment. If you want to format the JSON, then you will have to write some JS that converts the JSON to HTML. Or if the JSON has some text formatting already use an HTML <pre> tag.

Comment: upvote flag not seen in this post :(

Comment: There you go, created an answer out of the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to respond with a `Content-Type` header of `text/html` when serving the json files.

`send_file(abs_path + '/jsonfile.json', mimetype="text/html")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types